# How can I destroy a View?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I would like to destroy a View and the corresponding Controller as soon as  somebody is using the back button. This would give me the possibility to  avoid a reset function and i could use user-created content within the init method from the new controller.

But the sap-ui-core is throwing an `adding element with duplicate id` error messages, what did i wrong?

```js
var oView = sap.ui.view({
    id: id,
    viewName: "newController",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
})
oView.destroy();

oView = sap.ui.view({
    id: id,
    viewName: "newController",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
})
oView.destroy();
```

Comment: Just a suggestions from my side: I do no think that this is a good idea to use noDuplicateIds. Usually there is always a better way to achieve what you have in mind.

Comment: Please consider closing this Q&A since the issue is no longer reproducible in the maintained UI5 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old Answer - not recommended anymore**

i couldn't figure out, why these exceptions appear; independent from destroy() or deregister() calls.

But if somebody trapped to into same problem. You can deactivate the DuplicatedIds check from the framework over the bootstrap as a temporal workaround.

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-noDuplicateIds="false"
                >
</script>
```

---

**Update UI5 1.8x.xx**

A lot has changes, this bug was fixed a long time ago. Therefore i update the answer. BUT Views/Controller are handled now by the router

**if you need this, you don't follow best practise.**

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", { });

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview("a", { viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html() } )
oView.destroy();

oView = sap.ui.xmlview("a", { viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html() } )
oView.destroy();
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="view1.initial" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" > 
    <Button />
  </mvc:View>
</script>
```